# passing through special characters in password when using download.file

Tags: r, download, passwords, special-characters

I am trying to download a file using the `download.file` function. The URL I am using is password protected. My password however has multiple special characters in it and it is not letting me download my file. Is there a way I can bypass this without changing the password?

The password I am using includes the special characters '$' '@'

Below is the example and the error code I am getting.

```
download.file("http://myusername:P@$$word@myurl.com?$format=json", myfile.json, method = "auto")
```

'InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "multiple special characters"? Do you mean as in Unicode/non-ASCII?

Comment: the multiple special characters are $ and @. They are in my password also the error that is get in " InternetOpenUrl failed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try encoding the characters in your password:

```
password <- "P@$$sword"
password <- URLencode(password, reserved=TRUE)  # deal with @ and $

file.loc <- sprintf("http://myusername:%s@myurl.com?format=json", password)
download.file(file.loc, ...)
```